# apt-file update: No Index available

Tags: linux, debian-wheezy

Why do I get this message (“No Index available”):

```
Downloading Index http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/wheezy/main/Contents-amd64.diff/Index:
No Index available.
Downloading complete file http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/wheezy/main/Contents-amd64.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0 20.4M    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
File is up-to-date.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update `/etc/apt/sources.list` eventually you can generate a list [from here](http://debgen.simplylinux.ch/).

When I tried to check the link "http://http.debian.net/debian/dists/wheezy/main/" the browser redirected me to a *local* mirror ( it depends from the nation from where I'm connected).
It happens that the file that throw the error misses in this repository too.

So the suggestion is to *use different set of sources* and 
then to run the following commands with *sudo* or as *privileged user* (even without *sudo*)

```
  sudo apt-get clean  
  sudo apt-get update
```

---

Eventually you may find useful to clean by hands the directory

```
  sudo rm -r /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*
```

Comment: That's weird how `man apt-get` only mentions cleaning `/var/cache/apt/archives/` but doesn't mention deleting the pkgcache files, though it does ("simulate" indicates it'll `Del /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin`). I wonder if `update` on it's own would remove no longer needed/available info, or if it leaves old removed repo info

Comment: with `sudo apt-get clean` it should be able to clean the whole `/var/cache/apt/*` tree and not only the local archive for packages.

Comment: Read a bug report about `apt-get clean`'s new "feature", it's still undocumented too. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=661947

Comment: Maybe it's a problem of version; running `man apt-get` version 1.0 for ubuntu (compiled  Oct 28 2014 20:55:14
) it gives _"clean clears out the local repository of retrieved package files. It removes everything but the lock file from `/var/cache/apt/archives/` and `/var/cache/apt/archives/partial/`"_.

Comment: Yes, you see the problem is `/var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin` is outside of `/var/cache/apt/archives/`

Comment: I agree, I think it remains _hidden_ in the phrase _clears out the local repository of retrieved package file_ __s__, implying index and bin files too. They could be more clear.